# Why does $x^2=\frac{15-c}{8}$ have 2 roots if $c<15$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

I have this equation $8x^2+c=15$ and my goal is to find a value for $c$ when the equation has two roots.

I have come to $x^2=\frac{15-c}{8}$ and $c<15$. I don't understand the logic that when the right side is positive then the equation has two roots, why is that?

Comment: What are the roots of $x^2=1$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  A positive number has two square roots

Comment: I know that, but what is the reason for that, I can't understand the logic behind it? @J.W.Tanner

Comment: If $x^2=a$, then $(-x)^2=a$

Comment: @Zazh $(-x)^2$=$(-1)^2\cdot(x)^2=x^2$. So if $x^2=25$, then $x=\pm5$ as $(-5)^2=(+5)^2=25$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $c < 15$. Then we can rewrite the given expression as
\begin{align*}
8x^{2} + c = 15 & \Longleftrightarrow x^{2} + \frac{c-15}{8} = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x^{2} - \left(\sqrt{\frac{15-c} {8}}\right)^{2} = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \left(x - \sqrt{\frac{15-c}{8}}\right)\left(x + \sqrt{\frac{15-c}{8}}\right) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x = \pm\sqrt{\frac{15-c}{8}}
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!